# AttributeError: 'Ballons' object has no attribute 'image'

Tags: python, pygame

I can't find the mistake. Trying for hours.

When I run the code, I get the message:

Ballons' object has no attribute 'image'

The message in detail:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\pythonprogramm\ballon_jagd copy.py", line 47, in 
ballon_sprites.draw(spielfeld)
File "C:\Users\chef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 546, in draw
surface.blits((spr.image, spr.rect) for spr in sprites)
File "C:\Users\chef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 546, in 
surface.blits((spr.image, spr.rect) for spr in sprites)
AttributeError: 'Ballons' object has no attribute 'image'

Here is the code:

```
 class Ballons(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)     

        z_bild = pygame.image.load("Bilder/ballons/ballon1.png")       
        self.einzel_bild = z_bild
        self.rect = self.einzel_bild.get_rect()
        self.rect_x = random.randint(100,1800)
        self.rect_y = 700 
        
    def update(self):        
        self.rect_y -=5

def draw_bg():
    spielfeld.fill(bg)

#Allgemein..............................................
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
bg = (50,250,50)

#Spielfeld.............................................. 
bild_breite = 1920
bild_hoehe = 1080
spielfeld = pygame.display.set_mode((bild_breite,bild_hoehe))

#Erstellung Sprite und Group

ballon_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
ballon = Ballons()
ballon_sprites.add(ballon)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
   
    #Zeichnen        
    draw_bg()    
    ballon_sprites.draw(spielfeld) 
    ballon_sprites.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)nter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

[`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect`. [...]

Therefore a `Ballon` must have an attribute with the name `image`:

```py
class Ballons(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)     

        self.image = pygame.image.load("Bilder/ballons/ballon1.png")       
        
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect_x = random.randint(100,1800)
        self.rect_y = 700 
        
    def update(self):        
        self.rect_y -=5
```